# How to integrate a matlab project in C# windows application

Tags: asp.net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have developed a project of"Automatic Number Plate Reader" in matlab and I want to call this project in C# windows application for further process.But when i implement this in C# i got a error:

> MWArray assembly failed to be initialized.

I have generated all the dll files in matlab and added it in the reference of the C# project from the deploytool in matlab. And MWArray.dll have also been added.

I am using 2013a version of matlab and 2012 version of Visual Studio.

Comment: It might be that there are some compatibility issues between the versions, check this link for more details http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/index.html?sec=win32

Comment: Thxs for ur reply.I think there is no issue with the compatibility.I want to know whether i am missing any of the dll's in .net

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the error in your Develop machine? I suspect not.

When you distribute a software that uses matlab Dll's you need to install [Matlab Runtime Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) (AKA MCR) in order to allow the machine using the software to run the Matlab code.

If you get the same error after installing the MCR, Try running it again with an Administrator user.

Comment: The mcr is being installed.Running with Administrator user also did not help.

Comment: The error i got was at the time of executing it in the C#.So i think the error was at the develop machine only.

Comment: @bksumedha I Understand the error was during C# code trying to access the Matlab code. The question is does this happen during develop time or on another computer after published.

Comment: ...Its happening at the develop time only.

Comment: @bksumedha just for being on the safe side, did you make sure your IDE runs with administrative privileges?

Comment: yes, its running with the administrative privilages.

Comment: Do u have any document regarding this consisting of examples.

Comment: I Recommend building a new **minimal** program the demonstrates this issue. Once you have it, try to make it work. If you will do that, I don;t mind taking a look at this **Minimal** project. Just make sure it has ONLY code that is mandatory for demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Thanks for it.. will look into it and tell u.